Why does it look like the probability exceeding 1? How do you solve this problem?
This problem comes from a swedish probability and statistics book and reads as follows:
"A company manufactures a type of appliance with a one-year warranty. Due to different uses of the devices, the probability of them breaking during the warranty period varies from device to device. This probability can be considered as a random variable with density function:
$f(x) = 2(1 - x)$ if $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $= 0$ else.
Determine the probability that a randomly selected appliance lasts the warranty period."
As we can notice, P("The appliance breaking within 1 year") = 1 [integrating the densityfunction from 0 to 1], which would suggest that P("The appliance breaking outside the timespan of 1 year") = 0 due to this being the complement of that event. The answer is supposed to be 2/3. How can P("The appliance breaking within 1 year") = 1 and $P("The appliance breaking outside the timespan of 1 year") = 2/3 hold at the same time as the probability sum exceeds 1? Is there an easy and intuitive way of explaining this, and how do you solve the problem with that information?

The title makes no sense. Probabilities are always in the interval $[0,1]$. A result outside this interval can never be valid.

Not sure what you are asking.  We have no information regarding the probability that it breaks outside the warranty period, and you aren't asked anything about that.

To understand the question, consider a simpler version.  Suppose there are two appliances, one of which has a $\frac 1{10}$ chance of failing during the interval in question and the other has a $\frac 14$ chance of failure in that same period.  You take one, uniformly at random...what is the chance that your chosen appliace will fail in that period?

@Peter Sorry for the bad title. You see, what I mean is that  P("The appliance breaking within 1 year") = 1 seems to be holding as well P("The appliance breaking outside of the timespan of 1 year") = 2/3. They are complements to each other and add up to 5/3.

You are misreading the question.  What the density function is telling you:  each unit that you pick has some probability of failing in the specified period.  That probability is itself uncertain and is given by a draw from a known distribution.  The density function tells you the distribution the probability is drawn from.  Look at my simplied variant.  In that case, we have a two state (discrete) distribution, in your case, the distribution is continuous.

@lulu Thank you for responding. As I understand the discreet case-example you gave above and how you try to relate it to my problem is that, the probablity of the chosen appliance failing in that period is (1/2) * (1/10) + (1/2) * (4/10) = 1/4, where 1/10, and 4/10 are the probabilities. In my case the probablity of a specific appliance X_j failing withing the timeperiod is given by $p(x_j) = \int_{0}^{1} 2(1 - x_j) dx_j = 1$.

@lulu So if I had two appliances with this probability of failing withing the 1 year, the probability of a randomly chosen appliance failing withing 1 year would be (1/2) * 1 + (1/2) * 1 = 1 ? I am surely missing something here, am I not?

That is obviously wrong.  If you are unlucky, you get the $\frac 14$ appliance but even then you only have a $25%$ of a fail.  You are forgetting to weight by the probabilities.  You get the $\frac 14$ and the $\frac 1{10}$ one each with probabiliy $\frac 12$, so the expected fail probability is $\frac 12\times \frac 14+\frac 12\times \frac 1{10}$, the average of the two probabilities.  Of course, for a continuous distribution, you need an integral instead of the simple sum, but the idea is the same. You want the expected probability.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
We are after the expected probability of failure, and we compute that as   $$\int_0^1 x\times 2(1-x)\,dx=\frac 13$$
Thus you expect the, randomly selected, appliance to have a failure probability of $\frac 13$, which means you expect it to have a success probability of $1-\frac 13=\frac 23$, as claimed by the official solution.
To stress:  "failure" and "success" are defined only relative to the warranty period, the first year.  We are given no information about what happens after that first year nor are we asked about it.
